# Higlight the dominating number in excel, most repeated for each keyword

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula

Is this possible using excel formulas? To find keyword and number then match and color the highest number for that specific keyword, e.g. below:

[image]

this is the list Cell A keyword and B numbers
shoes       9
shoes       5
shoes       3
furniture   2
furniture   4
furniture   5
beauty      6
beauty      8
health      35
health      4
health      2
grocery     3
grocery     2
computers   9
computers   7
laptop      2
laptop      11
laptop      2
laptop      6
pets        9
pets        3
books       5
books       5

[image]

shoes       9 Highlight this number
shoes       5
shoes       3
furniture   2
furniture   4
furniture   5 Highlight this number
beauty      6
beauty      8 Highlight this number
health      35 Highlight this number
health      4
health      2
grocery     3 Highlight this number
grocery     2
computers   9 Highlight this number
computers   7
laptop      2
laptop      11 Highlight this number
laptop      2
laptop      6
pets        9 Highlight this number
pets        3
books       5 ignore if its equal
books       5

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional formatting, choosing "Use a formula..." and use a formula such as `=b1=maxifs($B$1:$B$100,$A$1:$A$100,a1)`. Be mindful of absolute vs. relative reference to ensure that you're tracking the right ranges.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your formula in conditional formatting, use as formula, it didnt trigger for some reason.

Comment: The way I wrote the formula, you need to first select your highlightable range, with cell B1 as the active selected cell. If any other cell is the active cell, the formula will fail

Answer (score 1):

In particular when tagged [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) you should be showing what you have tried. [macros](/questions/tagged/macros) Usage guide specifically states "DO NOT USE for VBA / MS-Office languages" and [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) wiki states "Questions tagged with [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) should be version-agnostic.". However, with a formula is possible in versions earlier than those with MAXIFS (ie not: Excel for Office 365 Excel for Office 365 for Mac Excel 2016 Excel 2016 for Mac Excel Online Excel for iPad Excel for iPhone Excel for Android tablets Excel for Android phones Excel Mobile), if in a more long-winded way:

Assuming you have `11` in B18. Add a column (say `I`) and populate I1 with `0` and enough of it from I2 downwards with:

```
=IF(A1<>A2,I1+1,I1)
```

copied down to sort your data on ColumnI Smallest to Largest then by ColumnB Largest to Smallest (to preserve the order of the values in ColumnA).

Then select B2 down to as far as required, clear any existing CF rules from it and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(A1<>A2,B2<>B3)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

The above should not, as specified, highlight the values for `books` though if working I suspect @nutsch's current answer might.

---

Sorry, I forgot to adjust my guess for what was where, once I realised a header row would make things easier.

[image: CF example]

This does though stil have a problem, in that text that changes from one row to the next but shares the same quantity, one row to the next, will not trigger highlighting - a more complex formula may be required.

Comment: its highlighting some, but its incorrect, can you share a snapshot of the output.

Answer (score 0):

based on @pnuts idea, found a simpler way to do it.

Sort Z to A of B row, then sort column A,  A to Z, with expand the selection for both

next write a formula to highlight duplicates excluding the first one from column A and drag down the formula, it higlights all the correct ones.

thank you